# How to convert json array to model class in flutter dart/

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, model

```
{
    "feed": {
        "entry": [
            {
                "im:name": {
                    "label": "The Rise"
                },
                "im:image": [
                    {
                        "label": "https://cover.jpg/55x55bb.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me how to create a dart class for this response. I tried with many online converters also. But when i implemented that code in real time showing lots of error.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
class Model {
  Feed? feed;

  Model({this.feed});

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    feed = json['feed'] != null ? new Feed.fromJson(json['feed']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.feed != null) {
      data['feed'] = this.feed!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Feed {
  List<Entry>? entry;

  Feed({this.entry});

  Feed.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['entry'] != null) {
      entry = <Entry>[];
      json['entry'].forEach((v) {
        entry!.add(new Entry.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.entry != null) {
      data['entry'] = this.entry!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Entry {
  ImName? imName;
  List<ImImage>? imImage;

  Entry({this.imName, this.imImage});

  Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    imName =
        json['im:name'] != null ? new ImName.fromJson(json['im:name']) : null;
    if (json['im:image'] != null) {
      imImage = <ImImage>[];
      json['im:image'].forEach((v) {
        imImage!.add(new ImImage.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.imName != null) {
      data['im:name'] = this.imName!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.imImage != null) {
      data['im:image'] = this.imImage!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class ImName {
  String? label;

  ImName({this.label});

  ImName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    label = json['label'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['label'] = this.label;
    return data;
  }
}
```

[Json To Dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) does it effectively.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in real time, when i pasted this code in dart class. v.toJson() is showing error in --> data['im:image'] = this.imImage!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();

Comment: I don't quite get, what error does it throw?

Comment: Sry, actually error occurs in --> data['feed'] = feed!.toJson(); <-- The error says "The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'Feed'. "

Answer (score 0):

**Json to and from Dart Class:**
Just use online dart code generation sites like below:

1. https://app.quicktype.io/
2. https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

One correction may needed. Remove @ from @required.

I think this is the best way.
build_runner is good but sometime painful.
So, I adopted this method.
It works best for me.